Thread slowdown when changing tabs in Unity WebGL
I'm making a game with Unity WebGL. When I change the tab, the thread slows down, so when I make
AudioListener.pause = true;

the sound turns off with a delay of 2-3 seconds. My browser is Chrome. How can I intervene the Main Thread immediately when the tab changes.
Main thread cannot be back to me right way.

In regular HTML, you'd listen for the visibilitychange event. Maybe you can do that in the page hosting the Unity game and somehow signal that to the game.
